# Get request throws a NullReference Exception only at the back-end

Tags: c#, angular, api, asp.net-core, get

I'm Trying to make a get Request

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetOrders()
{ 
  int marketingId = 
            int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value);
  var orders = await _repo.GetMarketeerOrders(marketingId);
  var ordersToReturn = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MarketeerOrdersDto>> 
            (orders);
  return Ok(ordersToReturn);
}
```

and this is GetMarketeerOrders Function

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<OrderDetails>> GetMarketeerOrders(int id) 
        {
            var orders = await _context.OrderDetails.Include(i => 
 i.Option).ThenInclude(i => i.Product).Include(i => i.Order).ThenInclude(i => 
 i.Bill).Where(i => i.Order.MarketingId == id).OrderBy(i => 
 i.Order.OrderDate).ToListAsync();
            return orders;
        }
```

but it throws the following exception when making the request, in my case I'm using Swagger UI

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at API.Controllers.MarketeerOrdersController.GetOrders() in /Users/ahmedgamal/projects/Drop Shipping/API/Controllers/MarketeerOrdersController.cs:line 27
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:5000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Referer: http://localhost:5000/swagger/index.html
sec-ch-ua: "Not_A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="109", "Chromium";v="109"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty

Response headers
 content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 
 date: Mon,06 Feb 2023 13:34:48 GMT 
 server: Kestrel
```

It comes to this line of code when debugging

```
 int marketingId = int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value);
```

Then it stops and throws the exception
But when using the same request from the client-side using angular and subscribe it by storing the response into some variable like this

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.marketeeerOrdersservice.getOrders().subscribe(d =>{
      this.allOrders = d;
    });
  }
```

and this is the getOrders Method

```
getOrders(){
     return this.http.get<MarketeerOrders[]>(this.url);
  }
```

Then there is no problem at all
What is the reason I can't figure it out
Is it because I should always store the response in a variable ?
I don't think so because other requests work properly without having to do this

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that LocalStorage where i've stored my token is a frontend concept. It is accessible to JavaScript running in the browser. asp.net resides on backend and can not access the LocalStorage directly.
You'd need to access it through the scripts running in frontend which can communicate with backend using Ajax requests.